# How to use the data in this class to be emailed?

Tags: java, string, email

in the code below which i receive from serial monitor read, i need to use the information for javamail. Is there any way i can extract the data to be placed in the java mail?

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {

            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            String[] parts = inputLine.split(",");
            String part1 = parts[0]; 
            String part2 = parts[1];
            String part3 = parts[2];
            String part4 = parts[3];
            part12User.usePart1Part2(part1,part2,part3,part4);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

And the javamail code body:

```
public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,       //generate email.
MessagingException {

    String[] toEmails = { "*******@gmail.com" };
    String emailSubject = "Speed Violation Summon Issued";
    String emailBody = "";    //data to be used here
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because value1 to value4 is null when calling `EC.userdata(value1, value2, value3, value4);`

Comment: You have two `EmailClient` instances, you're probably getting the values from the one on which you never call `userdata(value1, value2, value3, value4);`

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in questions, with proper indentation.

Comment: EmailClient has a parameterzied constructor so use that

Comment: It's a serious error in your logic. You have four non-instantiated values, meaning they have the default value null, and when you actually call the setter, you just pass the reference to those same values (which are still null) to set them

Comment: @Raghavendra: Where do you see a parameterized constructor?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry use userdata method or change to constructor

Comment: @calvin You have to do things when Sir Jon himself ask

Comment: @Raghavendra: That's not a class - it's just a `void` method, which is being called using the existing instance variables from a different instance.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you (the OP) are expecting the values to be... you're calling `userdata` passing in the *existing* values in the original instance, which are never set elsewhere. Where do you expect any new information to come from? It's unclear why you have two instances of `EmailClient` at all. I strongly suggest you look carefully at all of this code and try to understand what's going on now (maybe via debugging) and consider changing the design.

Comment: This is not how to define array of string `String[] toEmails = { "calvinern@gmail.com" };` it should be `String[] toEmails = new String[] { "calvinern@gmail.com" };`  **AND** show us the `sendMail()` method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've change the way of eleborating the problems. Where I need to use the data from the Serial Monitor read to the EmailClient class. I've Edited the question and code. Sorry for any inconvenience cause.

Comment: @Jens   I've change the way of eleborating the problems. Where I need to use the data from the Serial Monitor read to the EmailClient class. I've Edited the question and code. Sorry for any inconvenience cause.

Comment: @Stultuske  I've change the way of elaborating the problems. Where I need to use the data from the Serial Monitor read to the EmailClient class. I've Edited the question and code. Sorry for any inconvenience cause.

Comment: Now we've only got bits of code, and no indication of what you're actually observing. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect it doesn't really need to touch JavaMail.